# Django : TypeError: static() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to view my uploaded image through web-browser/DRF-browsable API. So I added `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` to my setting.py file. When I trying to run the code , it showing  `TypeError: static() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'` . 
Here is my relevant portions of code,

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Images')
MEDIA_URL = '/Images/'
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.templatetags.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'project.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^health$', health),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^sample/',sampelview),
    url(r'myapp/',include(myRouter.urls)),
    url(r'^test/$', testRequest),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 12):

This error is due to you are imported wrong References of *static*.Try to use `from django.conf.urls.static import static` instead of `from django.templatetags.static import static`